# Is there an ng-directive or a default function, which can be used as a scope.watch-function

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a component, that has an `@NgOneWay` binded attribute `message`. I have `{{cmp.message}}` within my html template and it will update automatically when attribute changes. If I want to run a `myFunc`-function, when `cmp.message` changes, I can use `_scope.watch('message', (newValue, oldValue) => myFunc(), context: this);` in my constructor.

Is there a default function, which will fire when my `message`-attribute changes, like `onMessage()`?

Or ng-directive, which could be used instead of `watch`, like `ng-onmessage="cmp.myFunc()"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest (and IMHO most beautiful) solution is to implement your `cmp.message` as getter/setter and execute your function in the setter.
This way you don't need a watch at all.

```dart
var _message;
@NgOneWay
get message => _message;
set message(val) {
  _message = val;
  myFunc();
}
```

Comment: You're right, I knew this, but I just missed it. Thank you.